# What is the difference between Mass email and single email?

Tags: singleemailmessage, massemailmessage

i'm writing some code that is going to be sending email reminders to customers. I don't know whether to use single email with a loop to generate all the emails and send them out as a list or to use mass email which I haven't used yet.

Both of these have a limit of 5000.

What does mass email do better than single email? I'm just thinking about limitations here and if mass email would be better for avoiding hitting the daily limit.

Comment: Refer this : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5169/whats-the-advantage-of-using-massemailmessage-instead-of-multiple-singleemailme